# Expandable background image

Tags: html, css

I have an iPad as a background image

But am looking to make it so that it is expandable, hopefully part of the header, footer, and then the middle part expands necessary to the length of the page.

Looking for any advice to get that effect, not sure which technique to use right now.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `border-image` when you don't want to slice the image. Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/FsFLm/

```
.ipad {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 143px 55px 144px;
    -moz-border-image: url(http://www.exampe.com/image.jpg) 143 55 144 repeat;
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://www.exampe.com/image.jpg) 143 55 144 repeat;
    -o-border-image: url(http://www.exampe.com/image.jpg) 143 55 144 repeat;
    border-image: url(http://www.exampe.com/image.jpg) 143 55 144 fill repeat;
    /*just for the demo*/
    height: 2000px;
}
```

Because i'am lazy the code was generated by http://border-image.com

Comment: Thanks, went with this = didn't know about this trickery but it's working well in this case, also able to stretch the width of it and make it wider which was on my todo list. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could position the background then stack elements, in the example below- you can keep adding as many `div` elements as you wish in 1000px blocks. That said- you'd be better creating a new image for the middle part, it will then repeat vertically meaning it can be any height.

Alternatively- why not make the 'screen' section scrollable?

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Le5v3/2/)

HTML

```
<header></header>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<footer></footer>
```

CSS

```
div, header, footer {
    background-image:url(http://www.propertyitguy.co.uk/img/tablet-bg.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
header, footer {
    height:100px;
}
footer {
    background-position:0 -1400px;
}
div {
    background-position:0 -200px;
    height:1000px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's an awesome solution, both awesome solutions but went with the border-image in this case

Comment: @Jamie000012 - using a border image is the way to go- its more flexible

Comment: That's good to hear I am not choosing the lousy/lazy solution! One of the reasons was that I had to expand the width of it too, border image works well here. Thanks again though!

Edit: also the alternative solution was cool - if I thought of that I would of probably gone for that from the start